# Spring DatasourceTransaction Manager Problem

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactionmanager

```
final DataSource ds = DataSourceLocator.getInstance()
    .getDataSource(sg.cmpl.starhub.lprs.Constants.APP_KEY);
final DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
txManager.setDataSource(ds);

final DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
def.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED);
final TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try {

    /***************************************************************************/
    conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(ds);
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.execute();
    /***************************************************************************/

    txManager.commit(status);

} catch (Exception e) {
    txManager.rollback(status);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my transaction manager logic? It looks like unstable. When I insert new data, First time it seems to save and later I can't find the data in mysql database. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a special reason you want to do programmatic connection and transaction management I suggest taking a look at Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and wrap it's usage in a `TransactionTemplate`.

However as stated in the previous comment, you should try to avoid programmatic transaction management as much as possible and use annotations (`@Transactional`) or XML configuration (`TransactionProxyFactoryBean` or `<tx:advice/>`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something wrong.  This is not the Spring way.  You should not be putting commit/rollback logic in code like this.  The advantage comes when you can do it declaratively, in configuration.

Have a look at the [Spring transaction reference docs](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: according to Spring documentation if commit operation fails with TransactionException then rollback was already called and calling it again in catch block will trigger IllegalTransactionStateException.